# Why MyClass::class.java.simpleName can't be constant value?

Tags: kotlin

A normal `val` is OK, and is initialized.

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = MyClass::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

But `const val` causes compilation error.

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = MyClass::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

error log

```
MyClass.kt:27:33: error: const 'val' initializer should be a constant value
        private const val TAG = MyClass::class.java.simpleName
```

It seems unintuitive that `simpleName` cannot be defined as a `const val`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Kotlin`, the `const` keyword should only be used when the value is a compile-time constant. Here `MyClass::class.java.simpleName` is not a compile-time constant. so we need to use `val` instead of `const`. `val` is same as the `final` keyword in Java.

For more info on this, please check [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/what-is-the-difference-between-const-and-val)

Answer (score 3):

> **Reflection** is a language's ability to inspect and dynamically call classes, methods, attributes, etc. at runtime.

Reflections can't be used at compile-time, they are only available at the runtime, so you can't use either of `::class` or `::class.java`, they won't be available at the compile-time.

The `const` modifier marks the val a compile-time constant. Hence can't call any runtime functions at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

`const` keyword is used to define compile-time constants but `val` can have runtime constants. simplename is not available at compile time hence the error.